# Obtener y leer archivo json de Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase

Estoy usando Firebase Storage para obtener la url de un `.json`, pero nose como acceder a los valores del archivo.
Por el momento solo quiero mostrar los valores en consola.

```
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
function obtenerInfo(){  
  const datosRef = ref(storage, `json/${numNC}.json`);
  console.log(datosRef)

  getDownloadURL (datosRef)
  .then((url) => {    
    console.log(numNC)
    console.log(url)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

has un fetch de la url:

```
const response = fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

aqui la documentacion de fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

por si se te hace util :)